# docker container hanging when run dotnet new

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core

The dotnet new command hanging on microsoft/dotnet:latest docker image. My docker info see below. Does anybody face this issue please?

Details steps:
    1. I have installed the docker 1.11.2 on Ubuntu desktop 14.04. 
    2. I run docker command: docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:latest to
        download and run the dotnet enviroment.
    3. When the dotnet docker image loaded, I execute the command: dotnet new for creating new dotnet project. 
    4. It show the project created successfully, however it hanging and cannot be exit, and also cannot be stopped/killed by docker command

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 8
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-27-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.937 GiB
Name: Ubuntu-Dev-01
ID: FL3Q:PM66:QJEG:D6D3:5WNM:GKDT:64MQ:JYZ6:PEQL:DMGP:DHPY:CU3R
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you did and what happened (including command output, if any)?

Comment: I have installed the docker 1.11.2 on Ubuntu desktop 14.04. 
I run docker command: docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:latest to download and run the dotnet enviroment. 

When the dotnet docker image loaded, I execute the command: dotnet new for creating new dotnet project.

It show the project created successfully, however it hanging and cannot be exit, and also cannot be stopped/killed by docker command.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [this bug reported on the dotnet-docker repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/26) repo, which references [this bug on the docker repo](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180). Per [a comment there](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180#issuecomment-193708192), the fix is to upgrade to a newer kernel (but not too new, to avoid [another bug](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6016)).